# Citrix Workspace App - Installation Error

Tags: ssl, citrix

While installing Citrix workspace app only version 23.9 and 23.8 I am getting this error. While installing earlier version like 23.7 It is getting install but getting SSL Error.

[image: Citrix Workspace - Installation Error]

Comment: Have you installed `curl` as it requires; as don't forget `dpkg` requires you to manually install all *dependencies* yourself either before hand, or at the `dpkg` command.  Alternatively you could have used a `apt` type command instead, which would have downloaded & installed required dependencies.

Comment: Thanks mate. It's installed